# Concatenating commands in linux

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I want to start a process in linux terminal which after 2 seconds asks for username and password.

How do I do the process call and then send those credentials in a script?
I know I should be using echo and &&, but the problem is that the first process doesn't finish, therefore I am unable to concatenate commands using &&.

Thanks

Comment: `sleep 2 && echo I ask for username and password`

Comment: I didn't understand that... Could you explain please?

Comment: does the process really need to start and then wait 2 seconds? Since you already started it, it should occupy the terminal you're running it at and should take the input itself, not your scipt. Not saying it's impossible to do, but if you provided some context and why you need that (convince us that it's not just XY problem) someone might actually help

Comment: This is not a problem you should try to solve by sending the credentials after 2 seconds. You should look at the program's manual and see how to pass credentials programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first process hasn't finished, you'll need to run the commands in parallel. You can do this by sending the first process to the background with the `&` operator. To send the credentials to the first process should be a different question. You should investigate "inter process communication."

One option would be to write the credentials to a file that the first process can read from.

```
#!/bin/bash

process_that_needs_credentials &  # start in the background
# the script will continue immediately

sleep 2
read -rp "username: " username
read -rp "password: " password

(
  echo "$username"
  echo "$password"
) > credentials.txt
```